# Vnet to Vnet machines not pinging

Tags: azure, subnet, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I have the following scenario.

2 vnets (same location/location, but different resource groups)

vnetA: Address space 10.1.0.0/16
       Gateway subnet 10.1.1.0/24
       VM 10.1.0.5

vnetB: Address space 10.0.0.0/16
       Gateway subnet 10.0.2.0/24
       VM 10.0.1.7

They are both peered through vnet to vnet gateways, but machines cannot ping each other.
Could anyone please guide to documentation or give advice to this please?

Comment: you mention both peering and vnet to vnet gateways which are conflicting in this case. Can you elaborate on how the two vnets are communicating?

Comment: Did both vnet to vnet peering and vnet to vnet through virtual gateways

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't sound right. vnet to vnet peering (the relatively new feature) is not done using virtual gateways, it's done directly between vnets in the same region. We can't help you unless we understand how the relationship between your vnets is set up.

Comment: To clarify, I just wanted to mention that I tried both methods vnet peering and through virtual gateways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [Network Security Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg) rules associated to the VNet's Subnets or to the VM's NICs. Unfortunately there is no a specific rule for ICMP protocol, but TCP and UDP only. You have to come up with a rule that suites your needs with the `'any'` protocol (i.e. '*').

Instead of using ICMP, when you want to test network connectivity I would suggest to use some TCP protocol based tool like [Test-NetConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372891.aspx) and create proper rules in the NSG to let the network traffic pass.

Comment: Thanks, it was some discrepancy with the NSG

Comment: Or use PSPing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/